# JavaScript not working in Rails 4 app (works on JSFiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I've got two independent javascript files:

```
$('a.tag').live('click', function(e){

// add selected class
$(this).toggleClass('selected');

var newTag = '';
$('a.tag.selected').each(function(){

    // add separator
    newTag += ((newTag.length > 0) ? ', ' : '');

    // add value;
    newTag += $(this).text();
});
$('#tag').val(newTag);

return false;  
});
```

and:

```
// Get user selection text on page
function getSelectedText() {
if (window.getSelection) {
    return window.getSelection();
} else if (document.selection) {
    return document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return '';
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$('#copy1').click(function () {
    $('#input1').val(getSelectedText());
});
$('#copy2').click(function () {
    $('#input2').val(getSelectedText());
});
$('#copy3').click(function () {
    $('#input3').val(getSelectedText());
});
});
```

Which perfectly well here:

http://jsfiddle.net/8WbRu/ and [2 link removed]

But when I include them in my Rails 4 app they do not work:

https://github.com/jamieturner/sample_app/tree/importcsv

What is going on?

Comment: 2nd link: http://jsfiddle.net/Kaf3V/4/

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors in your browser when trying to run this?

Comment: Have you tried turning off Turbolinks?  I seem to remember Turbolinks doesn't call document ready... or something.  I've never left in enabled...

Comment: First question would be -- do you know your JS is actually being called from your app?